# XAML .net Text Block Animated Rotation

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, animation, rotation

Basic run down.

I have a windows form that Uses an element host object to switch between child XAML views. I am using a FontAwesome spinner icon to rotate and indicate that activity is happening. I have narrowed down that I either must not be setting the right property path, or I need something additional when trying to modify the angle.

The object in question:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="status_1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="288,95,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="&#xf110;" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="/InstallerPanes;component/App_Plugins/FontAwesomeIconsDD/assets/font-awesome/fonts/#FontAwesome" Visibility="Visible" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
```

The code to start the transformation after a button press:

```
status_1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
status_2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;


_ani = new DoubleAnimation(0,360, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
_ani.AutoReverse = false;
_ani.RepeatBehavior = System.Windows.Media.Animation.RepeatBehavior.Forever;

Storyboard story = new Storyboard();
story.Children.Add(_ani);
Storyboard.SetTarget(_ani, status_1);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_ani, new PropertyPath("(TextBlock.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"));
story.Begin(this);
```

If I change the PropertyPath to **PropertyPath("Width")** then I can see an animation happen causing the icon to slide sideways from the width expansion. So I know the rest of the setup works.

However I also know if I put in a bad path, then a fault occurs, so the original path must be valid to some extent. I also know that if I modify the XAML value for the Angle to some other value, an actual rotation occurs in rendering, so I know the rotation is possible. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this snippet:

```
<TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <RotateTransform Angle="0" x:Name="textRotation"/>
    </TransformGroup>
</TextBlock.RenderTransform>
```

and in codeBehind:

```
_ani = new DoubleAnimation(0, 360, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
_ani.AutoReverse = false;
_ani.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
textRotation.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, _ani);
```

Comment: Interesting that I didn't have to use the story board to make it run.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="status_1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="288,95,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="&#xf110;" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="/InstallerPanes;component/App_Plugins/FontAwesomeIconsDD/assets/font-awesome/fonts/#FontAwesome" Visibility="Visible" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
```

Comment: This Worked as well, and actually solves why my path was wrong. Gave the vote to the other comment for being 2 minutes faster and also simplifying my back c# code. Really wish I could check both as answers.